# What is considered being proficient in a programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, career

I am a college student looking to get into industry work soon and want to understand what employers consider 'proficient' when it comes to programming languages.  Right now, I understand that to mean that one can write a fully functional program without consulting any references.  However, is there a tangible project or projects that demonstrate proficiency with a language and its libraries?  Preferably projects that employers like to see in their candidates.  My portfolio is relatively weak right now so I want to build that up before I graduate.  Any recommendations are appreciated!

Comment: Remember what you (of necessity) learned before writing intelligibly?

Comment: For the vast majority of employers, it seems to mean "can answer a set of completely useless trivia questions that have no relation with actual problem solving skills and only prove the applicant is capable of memorizing a couple of dozen facts without understanding them".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't go with your definition:

> that one can write a fully functional program without consulting any references

1. "Hello World" and Deep Neural Networks are both fully functional "programs". The complexity matters..
2. In the office nobody expects you to handle a program from beginning to end. Depending on the size of the office and their assembly line your assignments will vary a lot. For most of the time, you'll be implementing methods within a larger program.
3. It is a normal practice to use the documentation ("reference") even if you're on a senior position you're not supposed to remember everything by heart. Every developer I know spends at least  30 min on Stack Overflow every working day.

What is perhaps more valued is a solid foundation, understanding how the language works under the hood, ability to write clean readable code and be a team player.

Beyond a certain level of proficiency, it is not a criterion anymore because if you have a solid understanding of the language you can learn how to implement any complex algorithm or data structure in a reasonable amount of time.

You can never LEARN the whole language, you learn the Grammar...

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. You're saying it's more about being competent enough that you understand a language's key elements and in turn be able to make meaningful contributions in a team setting?  Or at the very least, know that the tools you want to use exist?

Comment: Exactly! If you know the key elements and how they work in-depth,  how much resources they use, which one is the best fit in a particular situation and you can write readable code then you're proficient in that language. If above this level then how much exactly you know is not relevant anymore because you can independently fill the missing gaps.

Comment: That makes much more sense! Thank you!